# env on macOS doesn't apply environment variables

Tags: bash, macos, shell, environment-variables

I'm a bit confused by the following:

```
 /usr/bin/env  V=hello echo $V somestring
```

outputs only

```
somestring
```

not `hello somestring` like I would expect from `man env`.

However, the tail of

```
/usr/bin/env V=hello printenv
```

is

```sh
_=/usr/bin/env
V=hello
```

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env` sets the environment that's inherited by the child process that executes the command. But you're expanding the variable in the original shell, and passing the result as an argument to `env`.

Try this:

```
/usr/bin/env V=hello bash -c 'echo $V somestring'
```

The single quotes prevent the variable from being expanded in the original shell. Then you run a new shell process that expands the variable itself.

Comment: Though in this case, `env` is not needed. `V=hello bash -c 'echo $V somestring'` would do the same.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah, I'm not really sure why the `env` command is ever needed for setting environment variables. AFAIK, the main use of it is in shebang lines, just to be able to search `$PATH` for the actual interpreter.

Comment: I think this is the main use indeed. Some people also use it (without arguments) to dump the environment, though I would use `printenv` for this purpose. Also, in shells (like csh) where you can not modify the environment on the fly (just for one program invocation), you have to use `env` for this purpose.

Comment: @user1934428 In csh I usually wrote `(setenv var value; program)`

Comment: Yes, this would correspond to `(export var=value; program)` in bash. But `var=value program` might be considered simpler, and similarily `env var=value program` might be considered simpler too for csh addicts.